# run a function inside FOR every 10 seconds

Tags: jquery

I have this for inside my script:

```
for(var i = 0, l = eachLine.length; i < l; i++) {
 if(eachLine[i].length>0){
  doP(eachLine[i], +i);
 }
}
```

the for read lines from a string and call doP function.
What happens is it is too fast and cause some speed trouble in my webside depending on text size.

What I want is to call doP function every 10 seconds... in other words, I want for to wait 10 seconds to call doP function again... how can I make it work?

Comment: You are looking for `setInterval()` and remove the for loop. `:)`

Comment: Or, with the for loop, use `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @GoneCodingGoodbye `I want for to wait 10 seconds to call doP function again` - Looks like the use case, what say?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Can I get each line from a text without a loop?

Comment: can anyone give me an example?

Comment: @RickJoe You need a loop, but just add `setTimeout()` inside the loop.

Comment: @GoneCodingGoodbye You **need** a loop to fetch the data and delay the execution time using `setTimeout()`. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @GoneCodingGoodbye Right.. So with for loop, just to delay the exec, we need `setTimeout` and not `setInterval`.

Comment: @GoneCodingGoodbye You are right. Sorry. It is async...

Comment: @RickJoe: Q: Do you want the first line displayed immediately, or after 10 seconds?

Comment: @GoneCodingGoodbye immediately would be great

Comment: In that case use the recursive version, or wrap one of the other solutions in a small function so you can call it initially and then also from timer callback.

Comment: @RickJoe I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `setInterval()`

```
var i = 0, len = eachLine.length;
function looper(){
    if(i == 0)
        interval = setInterval(looper, 10000)
    if(eachLine[i].length > 0)
        doP(eachLine[i], ++i);
    if(i >= len) 
        clearInterval(interval);
}
looper();
```

```js
var eachLine = ["Hi", "there", "I", "am", "lines", "of", "text"];
var i = 0, len = eachLine.length;
function looper(){
    if(i == 0)
        interval = setInterval(looper, 2000)
    if(eachLine[i].length > 0)
        doP(eachLine[i], ++i);
    if(i >= len) 
        clearInterval(interval);
}
looper();

function doP(line, count){
    $('body').append(count + ": " + line + "<br/>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Using `setTimeout()`

```
var i = 0, len = eachLine.length;
function looper(){
    if(eachLine[i].length > 0)
        doP(eachLine[i], ++i);
    if(i < len) 
        setTimeout(looper, 10000);
}
looper();
```

```js
var eachLine = ["Hi", "there", "I", "am", "lines", "of", "text"];
var i = 0, len = eachLine.length;
function looper(){
    if(eachLine[i].length > 0)
        doP(eachLine[i], ++i);
    if(i < len) 
        setTimeout(looper, 2000);
}
looper();

function doP(line, count){
    $('body').append(count + ": " + line + "<br/>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @GoneCodingGoodbye I updated the answer. Over looked the end of loop. Still it'll error out. ;)

Comment: You have the logic reversed for the `clearInterval`. it will stop after first line.

Comment: Okay... Better now. Note: The first version will output line 1 after 10 seconds, the second version will output line 1 immediately

Comment: @RickJoe: No it does not use a `for` anymore.

Comment: @RickJoe No need to use for loop.

Comment: @RickJoe if you don't want the function to execute once on load, then use the latest answer.

Comment: @GoneCodingGoodbye I think my latest change takes care of the second version will outputing line 1 immediately. Did I do it right?

Comment: Sorry no. The first version now waits 20 seconds for the first line. You needed a function like your second example, so you could make an initial call then call inside `setInterval`.

Comment: yeah, it is kind complex!

Comment: @GoneCodingGoodbye I think in that case either one my my old version was correct, Seeing your comment I thought like `setInterval` executes function immediately.

Comment: `setInterval` is a bit misleading. It files every milliseconds, so an *initial* call is required. I added the other option no one covered as well (recursive slice of the array). The code is shorter than most solutions, but requires more thought to figure out how it works.

Comment: @GoneCodingGoodbye I added snippets to my answer. I think they work correctly.

Comment: OP just confirmed they want the first line displayed at time 0. You will need to wrap your update code in functions to do that.

Answer (score 2):

As you want the first line to display immediately, you need to wrap the code in a function, so that an initial call can be made.

The other example covers counters, so here is another option (using slice on the array with a recursive function).

### Commented recursive version:

```
function processLine(eachLine, count)
{
    // if there are any array entries left...
    if (eachLine.length){

        // Call the worker function the first line in the array
        doP(eachLine[0], count);

        // Wait 10 seconds then call this function recursively
        setTimeout(function(){

           // Slice the arrat to remove the entry already processed and pass an incremented counter
           processLine(eachLine.slice(1), count+1);
        },10000);
    }
}
// Do the initial call and start the process off
processLine(eachLine,1);
```

### Working snippet below:

I shortened the time delay for this example.

```js
var eachLine = ["Hi", "there", "I", "am", "lines", "of", "text"];

function doP(line, count){
 $('body').append(count + ": " + line + "<br/>");
}

function processLine(eachLine, count)
{
 if (eachLine.length){
    doP(eachLine[0], count)
  setTimeout(function(){
        processLine(eachLine.slice(1), count+1);
     },1000);
    }
}
processLine(eachLine,1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Using a repeated `setTimeout()` call:

```
var i = 0;
function processLine(){
    if(eachLine[i++].length > 0){
        doP(eachLine[i], i);
    }
    // if any entries left, process them pseudo-recursively via timer
    if(i < eachLine.length) {
        setTimeout(processLine, 10000);
    }
}
// Run initial first line immediately
processLine();
```

```js
var eachLine = ["Hi", "there", "I", "am", "lines", "of", "text"];
var i = 0, len = eachLine.length;
var i = 0;
function processLine(){
    if(eachLine[i++].length > 0){
        doP(eachLine[i], i);
    }
    if(i < eachLine.length) {
        setTimeout(processLine, 10000);
    }
}
processLine();

function doP(line, count){
 $('body').append(count + ": " + line + "<br/>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```